# Saving extracted array into new NetCDF file

Tags: python, netcdf, xarray

I have a NetCDF file which looks like this:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (time: 180, d2: 2, lat: 180, lon: 360)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) object 2000-01-15 12:00:00 ... 2014-12-15 12:00:00
  * lat        (lat) float64 -89.5 -88.5 -87.5 -86.5 ... 86.5 87.5 88.5 89.5
  * lon        (lon) float64 0.5 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 ... 356.5 357.5 358.5 359.5
Dimensions without coordinates: d2
Data variables:
    time_bnds  (time, d2) object ...
    lat_bnds   (lat, d2) float64 ...
    lon_bnds   (lon, d2) float64 ...
    zos        (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
Attributes: (12/45)
    Conventions:            CF-1.7 CMIP-6.2
    activity_id:            CMIP
    case_id:                23
    cesm_casename:          b.e21.BHIST.f09_g17.CMIP6-historical.009
    contact:                cesm_cmip6@ucar.edu
    creation_date:          2019-01-27T12:33:42Z
    ...                     ...
    variable_id:            zos
    variant_info:           CMIP6 20th century experiments (1850-2014) with C...
    variant_label:          r9i1p1f1
    branch_time_in_parent:  295650.0
    branch_time_in_child:   674885.0
    branch_method:          standard
```

I extracted a spatial partition of the data while retaining all the time slices:

```
lat_bnds, lon_bnds = [25, 50], [-85 + 360, -60 + 360]
lats = DS.variables['lat'][:]
lons = DS.variables['lon'][:]
lat_inds = np.where((lats > lat_bnds[0]) & (lats < lat_bnds[1]))
lon_inds = np.where((lons > lon_bnds[0]) & (lons < lon_bnds[1]))
lat_inds_2 = list(lat_inds[0])
lon_inds_2 = list(lon_inds[0])
DS_subset = DS.variables['zos'][:, lat_inds_2, lon_inds_2]
```

This extracted data DS_subset looks like this:

```
<xarray.Variable (time: 180, lat: 25, lon: 25)>
[112500 values with dtype=float32]
Attributes: (12/19)
    cell_measures:  area: areacello
    cell_methods:   area: mean where sea time: mean
    comment:        Model data on the 1x1 grid includes values in all cells f...
    description:    This is the dynamic sea level, so should have zero global...
    frequency:      mon
    id:             zos
    ...             ...
    time_label:     time-mean
    time_title:     Temporal mean
    title:          Sea Surface Height Above Geoid
    type:           real
    units:          m
    variable_id:    zos
```

Now I am trying to save this extracted data *DS_subset* as a new netcdf file:

```
new_filename = './data/newfile.nc'
xr.Dataset(DS_subset.to_xarray()).to_netcdf(path=new_filename)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Variable' object has no attribute 'to_xarray'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why did you use `np.where` when xarray has `.where` method? That would make you code easier. Also, `DS_subset` is a Variable object, so you can run directly `DS_subset.to_netcdf(path=new_filename)`